# AttributeError: module 'mod_wsgi' has no attribute 'subscribe_events'

Tags: apache2, mod-wsgi, django-2.0

I am using django 2.0, python 3.5, apache2, mod_wsgi. But my site is performing very slow. For finding the cause of the issue, I have embedded script as suggested by Graham Dumpleton in this link https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/228#issuecomment-331365102
But I am facing following error:
**AttributeError: module 'mod_wsgi' has no attribute 'subscribe_events'.** Any help would be much appreciated